# SQL select categories where items have different values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Category table:

```
CategoryID    Description
-------------------------
1             Red category
2             Green category
3             Blue category
```

And an Item table:

```
ItemID    CategoryID    Status
------------------------------
1         1             "New"
2         1             "New"
3         1             "New"
4         2             "Editing"
5         2             "Editing"
6         2             "Editing"
7         3             "Published"
8         3             "Published"
9         3             "Published"
```

This comes from a legacy application which I am porting to a new code base. I suspect the Status column on the Item table should really be on the Category table. How can I verify that there are no Items that have a different status than any other items that belong to the same Category?

I know I want to aggregate the Items that have the same CategoryID, so I tried:

```
select categoryid
from item
group by categoryid
```

This gives me the distinct Categories. Now I want to select the ones with two distinct Statuses:

```
select categoryid, count(status) > 1
from item
group by categoryid
having count(status) > 1
```

But this just gives me the number of Items in each Category. I'm terrible at SQL.

Comment: just leave the itemid out.. and you'll get all categoryids with varying status.

Comment: @samyi I don't think that's right. See the last sentence above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable A
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable
             WHERE CategoryId = A.CategoryId 
             AND [Status] <> A.[Status])
```

Comment: What is YourTable? Item?

Comment: @Koveras Well, `YourTable` is the `item` table, correct. It's a way of generalizing your answer, since first you said that you had a `Category` table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.CategoryId, 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i.Status) FROM Item i WHERE i.CategoryId=c.CategoryId)
FROM Category c
```

Answer (score 0):

@Koveras, this will give you all the categories with multiple statuses.

```
select categoryid
from (
  select distinct categoryid, status
  from item) t
group by categoryid
having count(*) > 1
```

Your currently accepted solution will work but will be less efficient. Here is another solution.

[See Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f39e0/3)